# Business logic into stored procedure - still confused

Tags: stored-procedures, business-logic-layer

I have read many [articles](http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2005/06/09/the-worst-possible-way-to-use-a-stored-procedure/%22articles%22) regarding why we should not have business logic in several places, but try to keep it in BLL code. I understand the point of easy maintenance, and clearer understanding what the code does.

However, I never found any explanation what should we do in cases when applying (repeating) some of the business rules to stored procedure would significantly reduce data transfer from database to client app?

For example, I am currently working os some statiscal data presentation over a longer period of time. Currently all business logic / rules are in bussiness Logic layer (dll). A user has an option to display some results on the month level for one year. This would mean that, if I am not to use business rules in stored procedure, I would need to return about 1,000,000 records, and then apply business rules to this records on the client side. However, if I am to apply business rules to stored procedure, then it would reduce the number of returned records to 12.

An example of applying business rules would look something like this:

```
 AVG(CASE WHEN Field1 IS NULL
               THEN CASE WHEN c.Field2 = 1
               THEN ( cap1.Field3 / cap1.Field4) * 60
               ELSE CASE
 ..... etc
```

so it is not a simple logic, but complex one. And since this kind of logic could repeat in many different stored procedures, that would be a candidate for a separate function in database, to avoid repetitive code.

So, what is the recommended way here? And **why**?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can still have business logic where it belongs and classify this stuff as more "calculations"?

Either way, you have a compelling reason to do the calculations in the database layer when you are at a million plus rows.  So I would keep the calculation in functions.  So in your example a reusable function would be used like:

```
SELECT AVG(dbo.fnFieldsEvaluate(Field1, Field2, Field3, Field5)) as FieldAvgs,
...
```

Or if it is used a lot, simple enough and only depends on the columns in a single row, a computed column in the table would be more convenient.

```
   CREATE TABLE dbo.Products 
   (Field1 ....,
    Field2 ....,
    RowEvaluatesTo AS CASE WHEN Field1 IS NULL
               THEN CASE WHEN Field2 = 1
               THEN(Field3 / Field4) * 60
               ELSE CASE ...
```

Your function dbo.fnFieldsEvaluat, (or a computed column), would provide the one place where that calculation lives.